# How do you export custom ambient module declarations to be available for use by a consumer?

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

I am creating a component library to be consumed by a secondary Node app (both using Typescript). In this component library, we have a number of ambient modules to help with typing/loading picture files, eg:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

as well as other types that are extended off of existing but incomplete types from 3rd party libraries... eg:

```
import * as vc from "victory-core";
import * as vl from "victory-label";

declare module "victory-core" {
  export interface CallbackArgs extends vc.CallbackArgs {
    index: number;
  }
}

declare module "victory" {
  export interface VictoryLabelProps extends vl.VictoryLabelProps {
    stringTicks?: string[];
    index?: number;
  }
}
```

This library is then compiled and built using Rollup, and consumed by the secondary app. The issue is that these types are not available to the consumer app - ie, if a component is trying to pass in a **stringTicks** arg as part of VictoryLabelProps, it will not be recognized as a valid prop.
Similarly with the *.png* module, I cannot load up a png file in my consumer app unless I literally copy and paste the `.d.ts` file and explicitly add it as part of my consumer app

Below is my **tsconfig** for my component library:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```

(I tried adding typeRoots and baseUrl based on https://elfi-y.medium.com/typescript-ambient-module-8816c9e5d426)

and my **rollup.config**:

```
{
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      dir: "dist",
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  external: ["fs"],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    commonjs({
      include: "node_modules/**",
    }),
    resolve(),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
      extensions: [...DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS, ".ts", ".tsx"],
      presets: [["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }]],
    }),
    typescript(),
    json(),
    image(),
    url({
      include: ["**/*.woff", "**/*.woff2"],
      limit: Infinity,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `types` field in the `package.json` of your library. The field should contain the path to the `.d.ts` directory or file.

```
{
  "name": "awesome",
  "author": "Vandelay Industries",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./lib/main.js",
  "types": "./lib/main.d.ts"
}
```

More info:[Including declarations in your package](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package)